# MongoDB geospatial index in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, geocoding, geospatial, mongodb-.net-driver

I have been trying to get started but run into the same rock time after time trying to create and query MongoDB with C# official driver. The problem is how to create data with geo information. I am just not finding the answer.

Code:

```
MongoUrl url = new MongoUrl("mongodb://xxx.xx.x.xx/mydb");
MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(url);
MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("mydb");
```

<-- this works fine

```
BsonDocument[] batch = {
                         new BsonDocument {
                                             { "name", "Bran" },
                                             { "loc", "10, 10" }
                                         },
                                        new BsonDocument {
                                            { "name", "Ayla" },
                                            { "loc", "0, 0" }
                                        }
            };

places.InsertBatch(batch);
```

<-- that part is wrong somehow

```
places.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys.GeoSpatial("loca"));
var queryplaces = Query.WithinCircle("loca", 0, 0, 11);
var cursor = places.Find(queryplaces);
foreach (var hit in cursor)
{
    foreach (var VARIABLE in hit)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE.Value);
    }
}
```

<-- I think that part should show both documents, now showing none. A simple find shows them both.
Would be happy for some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking and searching I found the answer here: https://github.com/karlseguin/pots-importer/blob/master/PotsImporter/NodeImporter.cs

This to be read with my first piece of code as this fixes it.

```
  MongoCollection<BsonDocument> places =
               database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("places");

            BsonDocument[] batch = {
                                       new BsonDocument { { "name", "Bran" }, { "loc", new BsonArray(new[] { 10, 10 }) } },
                                       new BsonDocument { { "name", "Ayla" }, { "loc", new BsonArray(new[] { 0, 0 }) } }
            };

            places.InsertBatch(batch);

            places.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys.GeoSpatial("loc"));

            var queryplaces = Query.WithinCircle("loc", 5, 5, 10);
            var cursor = places.Find(queryplaces);
            foreach (var hit in cursor)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("in circle");
                foreach (var VARIABLE in hit)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE.Value);

                }
            }
```

As a point of clarification:  The problem with the code in the question is that location information should not be stored as a string, but rather as an array of 2 elements (x, y).

Answer (score 6):

example below is in C# (it's important to note order in the array which is longitude, latitude- follows the more logical order of x,y as opposed to the more commonly used form where latitude precedes longitude) :

1.) first your class needs to have this:

```
public double[] Location { get; set; }

public double Latitude
{
    get { return _latitude; }
    set
    {
        Location[1] = value;
        _latitude = value;
    }
}

public double Longitude
{
    get { return _longitude; }
    set
    {
        Location[0] = value;
        _longitude = value;
    }
}

public MyClass()
{
    Location = new double[2];
}
```

2.) then here is some code to get you started with the official C# driver and doing an insert w/ use of geo indexing:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts object and creates GeoIndex on collection (assumes TDocument is a class
    /// containing an array double[] Location where [0] is the x value (as longitude)
    /// and [1] is the y value (as latitude) - this order is important for spherical queries.
    /// 
    /// Collection name is assigned as typeof(TDocument).ToString()
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dbName">Your target database</param>
    /// <param name="data">The object you're storing</param>
    /// <param name="geoIndexName">The name of the location based array on which to create the geoIndex</param>
    /// <param name="indexNames">optional: a dictionary containing any additional fields on which you would like to create an index
    /// where the key is the name of the field on which you would like to create your index and the value should be either SortDirection.Ascending
    /// or SortDirection.Descending. NOTE: this should not include geo indexes! </param>
    /// <returns>void</returns>
    public static void MongoGeoInsert<TDocument>(string dbName, TDocument data, string geoIndexName, Dictionary<string, SortDirection> indexNames = null)
    {
        Connection connection = new Connection(dbName);
        MongoCollection collection = connection.GetMongoCollection<TDocument>(typeof(TDocument).Name, connection.Db);
        collection.Insert<TDocument>(data);
        /* NOTE: Latitude and Longitude MUST be wrapped in separate class or array */
        IndexKeysBuilder keys = IndexKeys.GeoSpatial(geoIndexName);
        IndexOptionsBuilder options = new IndexOptionsBuilder();
        options.SetName("idx_" + typeof(TDocument).Name);
        // since the default GeoSpatial range is -180 to 180, we don't need to set anything here, but if
        // we wanted to use something other than latitude/longitude, we could do so like this:
        // options.SetGeoSpatialRange(-180.0, 180.0);

        if (indexNames != null)
        {
            foreach (var indexName in indexNames)
            {
                if (indexName.Value == SortDirection.Decending)
                {
                    keys = keys.Descending(indexName.Key);
                }
                else if (indexName.Value == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    keys = keys.Ascending(indexName.Key);
                }
            }
        }

        collection.EnsureIndex(keys, options);

        connection.Db.Server.Disconnect();
    }


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace MyMongo.Helpers
{
    public class Connection
    {
        private const string DbName = "";
        private const string Prefix = "mongodb://";
        //private const string Server = "(...):27017/";
        private const string Server = "localhost:27017/";
        private const string PassWord = "";
        private const string UserName = "";
        private const string Delimeter = "";
        //if using MongoHQ
        //private const string Delimeter = ":";
        //private const string Prefix = "mongodb://";
        //private const string DbName = "(...)";
        //private const string UserName = "(...)";
        //private const string Server = "@flame.mongohq.com:(<port #>)/";
        //private const string PassWord = "(...)";
        private readonly string _connectionString = string.Empty;

        public MongoDatabase Db { get; private set; }
        public MongoCollection Collection { get; private set; }

        public Connection()
        {
            _connectionString = Prefix + UserName + Delimeter + PassWord + Server + DbName;
        }

        public Connection(string dbName)
        {
            _connectionString = Prefix + UserName + Delimeter + PassWord + Server + DbName;
            Db = GetDatabase(dbName);
        }

        //mongodb://[username:password@]hostname[:port][/[database][?options]]
        public MongoDatabase GetDatabase(string dbName)
        {
            MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(_connectionString);
            MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase(dbName);
            return database;
        }

        public MongoCollection<TDocument> GetMongoCollection<TDocument>(string collectionName, MongoDatabase db, SafeMode safeMode = null)
        {
            if (safeMode == null) { safeMode = new SafeMode(true); }
            MongoCollection<TDocument> result = db.GetCollection<TDocument>(collectionName, safeMode);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I think this example is very much correct but a bit advanced

Comment: do you need to add index on each insert? or is it enough with adding an index on the mongo collection the first time and automatically each insert will have the index "refreshed"?

Comment: @iberodev this answer was written a very long time ago - I can't be sure it's still up to date